# Seeing if a checkbox is checked by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that sets a variable everytime a checkbox is clicked:

```
      function handleClick(cb) {
         alert('entered function');
          setTimeout(function () {

        if (cb.checked ) {
               $("#IsChecked").val('true');
           }
            else
               $("#IsChecked").val('false');

        alert('now my value is: '+ $("#IsChecked").val());
       }, 0);
   }
```

Heres my checkbox:

```
  <input id="MyCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="true" onclick="handleClick(this);" 
  name="MyCheckBox" checked="checked">
```

This works great everytime the checkbox is checked. But now i need to know if the checkbox is checked when the user clicks a button and has never touched the checkbox before. So i do this:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#IsChecked").val('default');

    $('#btnCheck').click(function (e) {
        var isComplete = $("#IsChecked").val();
        if (isComplete == 'default') {
            var cb = $('#MyCheckBox');
            handleClick(cb);
         alert('after handleClick ischecked is: ' + $("#IsChecked").val());
         }
     });
```

});

When i click my button and the checkbox is checked by default, i get these alerts in this order:

```
 entered function
 after handleClick ischecked is: default
 now my value is: false
```

If i check the checkbox to toggle it, i get these alerts as expected:

```
 entered function
 now my value is: false
```

In my handleClick event, the setTimeout is there because of IE so i cant get rid of it. How can i check to see if a checkbox is checked without having to click the checkbox itself? Thanks

Comment: Advice: use change event with checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 How can i check to see if a checkbox is checked without having to click
```

You can find out if checkbox is checked in javascript with click event by using val() method

```
$("#MyCheckBox").is(':checked')​​​​​​
```

Comment: I keep getting illegal character. Im doing this : var chk =  $("#MyCheckBox").is(':checked')​​​​​​;

Answer (score 2):

> How can i check to see if a checkbox is checked without having to click the checkbox itself?

`$('#MyCheckBox').prop('checked')` will tell you anytime whether the checkbox is checked or not.

However if you not only want to test its status, but also execute your `handleClick` function, then note that the function expects a **DOM element**, not a jQuery object as argument.
If you pass a jQuery object to your function, then `cb.checked` will always evaluate to `false`, since jQuery objects don't have a `checked` property (only DOM elements have).

You'd have to change your function call to:

```
handleClick(cb.get(0));
```

to extract the DOM element from the jQuery object.

Comment: I get an error cb.get is not a function. Im using jQuery.1.4.1

Comment: @user1202717: It should work, it is part of jQuery since 1.0: http://api.jquery.com/get/. Of course it does not if `cb` is not a jQuery object. Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/hhtuA/

Comment: @user1202717: But since it seems you don't want to do this (I assume that from your comment to the other answer), you can just ignore that part. Your question was not clear in that regard. `$('#MyCheckBox').prop('checked')` just works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that checkbox is checked from the button click event.

```
$("#IsChecked").is(':checked'); //returns boolean
```